# Is it possible to set up infinispan hotrod cluster having couple of nodes in on premises servers and one or two nodes on cloud (e.g. AWS).

Tags: infinispan

We are planning to use infinispan (7.2.x) as imdg for our application. We have few app servers on premises. However, on occasions when heavy load is expected, we deploy additional app servers on cloud (normally AWS).
We are exploring hotrod cluster to be used with our application. Is it possible to set up hotrod cluster having couple of nodes on premises and one or two nodes on AWS  so that all of the app servers can share the data in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically scale the cluster by starting new nodes and stopping old ones, while the cluster still operates (though, the performance can suffer some penalty when the cluster currently rebalances data between nodes).

However there's no out-of-the box utility that would spawn new nodes in AWS and start a node there, when the load on the cluster is high. You have to monitor the cluster & react on the state yourselves (using JMX, management consoles, WildFly's host controllers etc...).

Comment: Thanks Flavious. My query is - is it possible to have some nodes on AWS and rest of the nodes on non cloud (in premises) servers?

Comment: Yes, JGroups as the transport (communication) layer is quite flexible, so once the nodes can directly communicate to each other (are not behind a NAT), there's no problem in that. Though, you should either keep the nodes physically close to have low latency, or use asynchronous cross-site replication.